# best way to bind timer event created within a for loop

Tags: python, events, timer, wxpython, bind

I'm trying to write a python code which create and initialize *n* timers in a for loop and bind them to some events. The code bellow is an example of the way I'm doing it:

```
import wx

#dm1 = {a dewell times values dictionary}
#screens = [a list of dm1 keys]
trials = range(1, 3)
timers = range(0, 4)


class DM1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.Go = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Go!', pos = (600, 450))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BuildTimers, self.Go)

    def BuildTimers(self, event):
        self.timers = {} 
        cum_timer = 0

        for trial in trials:
            for timer in timers:
                key = (timer, trial)
                new_timer = wx.Timer(self)
                cum_timer += dm1[screens[timer]]
                new_timer.Start(cum_timer * 1000, False)

                new_timer.mykey = key 
                self.timers[key] = new_timer

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.Screens)

    def Screens(self, event):
        if event.GetEventObject() == self.timers[event.GetEventObject().mykey]:
            print event.GetEventObject().mykey
            if event.GetEventObject().mykey[0] == 0:
                print 'You bastard!'

            if event.GetEventObject().mykey[0] == 1:
                print 'you vicious...'                

            if event.GetEventObject().mykey[0] == 2:
                print 'heartless bastard!'

            if event.GetEventObject().mykey[0] == 3:
                print 'Oh It makes me mad!'

app = wx.App()
frame = DM1(None, title = 'IG', size = (wx.DisplaySize()))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The timers don't start at the time I specificate: the second loop of `trial` appear to overwrite the first. For example, the statement `print event.GetEventObject().mykey`, in the complete code, prints

(0, 1) (1, 1) (1, 2) (2, 1) (3, 1) (0, 2) (3, 1) (2, 1)

instead of

(0, 1) (1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (0, 2) (1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2)

I guess the problem is in the `GetEventObject`, but I don't know a better way to bind the timers to the events. Does somebody have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using wxPython, I find it wiser to let widgets generate its own id using default parameters. Then you just ask the widget for its widget id. It is a dangerous practice, meaning really tricky to debug, to use manual magic number id values and sent the widget's id values to that, especially for ids below 4000 as there are a bunch aready defined in the low range. Some internal methods will ask for "give me widget with id 1" for example and instead of getting some internal default widget, that method will get your timer widget instead.

Working with predefineds like TIMER_ID = 4000 or even more elusively buggy TIMER_ID = 4000 + someoffset, add additional maintainence costs to code.

I find the most flexable, reliable way is to user the id=-1 or id=wx.NewId(). Then say

```
ident = myTimer.GetId()
self.timers[ ident ] = myTimer
```

or

```
self.timers[ myTimer ] = myTimer
```

or

```
self.timers.append( myTimer )
```

where order is maintained and the index acts like how you've used the ID field in your code.

Another good practice is to avoid using "id" as a temp variable as there is the Python builtin function id() AND in wx, widgets have an id attribute too:

```
w=Widget(..., id=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, according to [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t359908-wxpython-using-more-than-1-timer.html), you should pass an id parameter to the timer. For your case, this is what I could come up with:

```
def BuildTimers(self, event):
    self.timers = {} 
    cum_timer = 0

    i = 0
    for trial in trials:
        for timer in timers:
            i += 1
            key = (timer, trial)
            new_timer = wx.Timer(self, id=i)
            cum_timer += dm1[screens[timer]]
            new_timer.Start(cum_timer * 1000, False)

            self.timers[i] = key

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, lambda event, i=i: self.Screens(event, the_id=i), id=i)

def Screens(self, event, the_id=None):
    print "In the timer id =", the_id, "which is", self.timers[the_id]
```

**Why what you did does not work**

You are setting an attribute of the Timer instance, then in your function, you use `GetEventObject()`. Obviously, the Timer is not an event object... The way you are doing it, all timers will call the same function without it being able to know which one is calling it. So I passed a unique parameter `id`, which needs to be an int I think. To do that I used a lambda. It should work, but I did not test it.

Also, as I saw [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/), you might not even need ids, just bind it to the timer, but then you might need to pass the key as a parameter directly. Something like (without `i`):

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, lambda event, k=key: self.Screens(event, the_key=k), new_timer)`

Comment: GetEventObject returns the widget or object that called the handler, so I don't really think there's anything wrong with that bit. Using static IDs though is a no-no in most cases, as DevPlayer mentioned. You don't have to pass a Timer (or any widget) an ID as wxPython will assign one for you.

Comment: I never really worked with timers but I searched a bit and found the thread I linked to, then I found the post on your blog and mentioned that way too.